# dcps are published as uncoded characters tridion 2013 broker

Tags: content-delivery, broker, 2013

After upgrading broker from `2009` to `2013 SP1`. When we publish DCP, content is going to Component Presentation table as wierd chinese like characters?

Any quick observation what could have gone wrong here?

Comments are appreciated.

> 挼湯整瑮ാ 㰠摉琾浣㠺ⴱ㌴㌷㰱䤯㹤਍†吼瑩敬䬾摩慚楮⁡畓数獲慴婲爠瑥牵獮琠⁯牢湩⁧畯⁴桴⁥瑳牡⁳湩琠敨氠瑩汴⁥湯獥⼼楔汴㹥਍†匼浵慭祲䐾扵楡‬䅕㭅䨠湡慵祲㈠ⰱ㈠㄰㨴䘠牯愠汬琠敨琠污湥整⁤档汩牤湥愠摮琠敨物瀠潲摵瀠牡湥獴漠瑵琠敨敲‬楋婤湡慩‬桴⁥睡牡ⵤ楷湮湩⁧档汩牤湥猧攠畤慴湩敭瑮挠湥牴ⱥ椠⁳景敦楲杮琠敨⁭⁡湵煩敵漠灰牯畴楮祴琠⁯

Comment: Please can you check to see if your question is a duplicate of this one http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/2967/129

Answer (score 3):

The Content Delivery database is basically off limits to you, so how the content is stored there is irrelevant, as you have an API to read the content in it.

What you are seeing is correct for SDL Tridion 2013, the content in the `COMPONENT_PRESENTATIONS` table is not in a human readable format when using standard viewers like Toad or the SQL Server Management Studio. So basically nothing went wrong, all is as expected.

See also [this answer](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/component-presentations-in-sql-2012-db-shows-up-as-a-different-encoding-with-201/2968/#2968) given by Likhan.