# Russian content in component delivered as ??? in tridion DD4t

Tags: dd4t, broker

I have created a component, That component contains Russain content. This content is stored as "???" in the Broker database.

In DD4T web application debugging mode component's data shown as "???". Is there any setting i am missing?

Comment: This question is going to need more detail before people can answer it. Firstly - if you are talking about what the data looks like when you look at it directly using database browsing tools, then this is expected. See http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/2967/129. If it's something else (i.e. you've tried actually putting the data on a page and it still doesn't display well) then please add some details about your encodings, publishing process etc. Please explain what you've tried, and what doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried to create a component with Russian content and publiched to broker database. And accessed that component from DD4T web application. Coponent's data is shown as "????" in debugging mode.

Comment: Just checked creating a static publishing model. there also content is published to .Html file as "?????".

Comment: So this was an encoding issue caused by Publication using `Default Code Page`. Were all the characters actually question marks?

Comment: Yes Correct Alvin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest setting your ASP.NET MVC (DD4T) app to use UTF-8 encoding.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: UTC encoding are correctly set. It is issue in Tridion. Because content is published as "????" instead of actual content

Comment: If UTF8 is properly configured then content is published correctly. This has been true for thousands of websites with Tridion before, it won't be different for you. Something is missing - Check Elena's 7 clues: http://elenaserghie.blogspot.nl/2012/01/7-clues-to-solve-character-encoding.html

Comment: Publication changed Default Code Page set as default setting, I have changed that to UTF8. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Great. Glad it's working now