# Dynamic Component Presentation Returns Unicode Han Characters

Tags: content-delivery

Community,

We have recently upgraded from 2011 to 2013 and are seeing a very strange scenario on the content delivery side. The dynamic component presentations are being returned to the webpage seemingly as Unicode Han Characters (搼癩椠㵤昢 etc), even though in the database I can see the valid html.

When using the jsp tag lib (tridion:ComponentPresentation) or java code (ComponentPresentationAssembler) we experience the issue, however using the content delivery webservice it is return correctly.

For background the publishing target is configured as JSP / Unicode (UTF-8), and the JSP page has pageEncoding set to utf-8.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should check this answer

[Component Presentations Encoding Issue][1]


  [1]: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/component-presentations-in-sql-2012-db-shows-up-as-a-different-encoding-with-201/2993#2993

Comment: After reviewing the answers to the question referenced above, I dug deeper into our CWA 2011 SP1 delivery environment and determined that the cd_*.jar files had not been updated to match the Tridion 2013 SP1 jars. (I assume the default CWA 2011 SP1 war contains either 2011 SP1 or 2013 GA jars). Once the jars were updated along with the necessary 3rd party jars, it appears that the environment is working correctly. It would be wonderful if there was a debug message or something telling you that the jars and db version were a mismatch!

Comment: Hi Daniel, it seems like I was hasty in closing this as a duplicate. Maybe you could add your comment as an answer to your question to help others in future. I'm not sure the Content Delivery is currently smart enough to tell you the DB has been upgraded! You could raise this with SDL support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close the loop on this issue, it turned out to be a version mismatch between the content delivery jar files and the broker database version.

CWA 2011 SP1 contains either 2011 SP1 or 2013 GA jars, and not the correct 2013 SP1 jars. The way in which dynamic component presentations are stored in the broker changed between those versions, hence the jars still believed the presentation content was stored in clear text , but it was being stored (correctly) as encoded.

Once the jars were updated along with the necessary 3rd party jars, the environment(s) are all now working correctly.