# Broker database - storage language

Tags: 2013-sp1, broker

We recently upgraded to 2013 sp1. After the upgrade, when we publish any content and look at the same content in broker database the content is stored in non-engligh (may be chinese or japenese) language however with odata query we are able to retrieve the content in english.

> For e.g. before upgrade if we publish a component with content
>   `<h1>QAG TESTING<h1>` then broker database will have the same value
>   however after upgrade, published content is: 格㸱䅑⁇䕔呓义㱇栯㸱

My question was: is storing data in broker database in non-english intentional? Is there any configuration by which we can change the language of broker database.

Answer (score 3):

The CONTENT field as of Tridion 2013 is encoded. So it is not non-English, it is just the encoding results.  The purpose, I believe, is to keep the database more of a blackbox and force the product to be used by supported interfaces, such as OData (as you've found out) or Broker API.

Comment: Funny! No, that's not the reason, but it could have been. I'll answer when I'm not in mobile-only-mode. As noted, API works as expected.

Comment: The purpose was to fix some encoding issues we've had in the past - not only did we change this encoding, we also added some columns in some tables specifying which encoding was used. See this question for more details: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/component-presentations-in-sql-2012-db-shows-up-as-a-different-encoding-with-201