# DD4T REST Service: Componentpresentation Output

Tags: 2013-sp1, dd4t-2

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 sp1, pages & components are published to broker DB as JSON format. Using DD4T 2.0 templates to generate JSON output.

Trying to consume the **page & component presentation data** from content broken in **Angular 2** site using the **DD4T Rest Service**. I can able to retrieve the page json in proper format. I tried to retrieve the component data using below API call.

```
Syntax:http://myurl/componentpresentation/GetContent/{publicationId:int}/{id:int}
Example: http://myurl/componentpresentation/GetContent/5/123
```

API call return output as encoded chinese characters instead of component JSON data. I assume some decoding is required.

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Bala, your question is not clear. Please update the exact requirement that you are trying to achieve. May be you can add more details like: what you have done already. If you are new with DD4T then please check the blogs. May be this will help(http://blog.trivident.com/setting-up-a-dd4t-20-web-application/).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by adding below lines of code inside **GetContent** method in **DD4T.RestService.WebApi** ==> **ComponentPresentationController**

```
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);
    content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Referred [Component Presentations in SQL 2012 DB shows up as a different encoding with 2013](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/component-presentations-in-sql-2012-db-shows-up-as-a-different-encoding-with-201) to fix the issue.