# Junk characters shown in Broker Database DCP publishing in SDL Web 8

Tags: content-delivery, odata, dynamic-publishing

We have recently upgraded one of our client's environment from SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 to SDL Web 8.1. When we are publishing any DCP its content is getting stored as junk characters in the Database table, due to which querying OData is resulting in junk characters.

Any suggestions/guidance will be really helpful.

Adding further to the above question:
When I query content using Content.svc I get the data in the correct format but when I query same using Odata.svc (Odata comes from an old SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 setup), I get junk characters.

Regards

Comment: Pls take a look at Elena's post it might help you http://elenaserghie.blogspot.com/2012/01/7-clues-to-solve-character-encoding.html

Comment: @K91, checking will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to point that content in Broker database is always encoded and it's correctly set as such. Since your `Content.svc` is returning properly decoded data, it means that problem is not in `Content.svc` service, but in legacy `Odata.svc`. From your question I guess your system is 8.5, so my question to you is why are you still using `Odata.svc` extension point? You can see the changes in naming in [following article.](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-10F5FF8A-81EC-4ECF-BC40-D8083956FA55&addHistory=true&query=content.svc&scope=&tid=cf5261ed-6a60-44fd-92c5-1ae262695c4b&filename=GUID-10F5FF8A-81EC-4ECF-BC40-D8083956FA55.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-10F5FF8A-81EC-4ECF-BC40-D8083956FA55&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dcontent.svc&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1544436167798&currentQuery=content.svc&currentScope=)

As additional note, you can use following query to get component presentation from broker database in decoded format.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), CONVERT(varbinary(max), CONTENT))
FROM COMPONENT_PRESENTATIONS
WHERE (PUBLICATION_ID = 118)
AND (COMPONENT_ID = 222) 
AND (TEMPLATE_ID = 333333)
```

Comment: Thanks, same solution we have concluded during our different troubleshooting sessions. Your answer adds weight to our findings.  Although our client wanted to stick with odata instead of content service, which we resolved using url rewrite. Thanks again.

Comment: heheheh creative solution i must add. :D

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an encoding issue, do the following in your deployer service.

1. Uninstall your deployer service
2. Go to your deployer service **\bin**
   folder and open to edit the **installService.ps1** file to add
   **-Dfile.encoding=UTF8** in the **$jvmoptions**

   > $jvmoptions = "-Xrs", "-Xms256m", "-Xmx256m","-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"
3. Also, To use the **jvm.xml** in your Content Delivery deployer service config folder to enable encoding

   > <Option Name="-Dfile.encoding" Value="UTF-8"/>
4. ReInstall your deployer service with **installService.ps1**
5. Republish your DCP to check your database

I hope it helps to fix this encoding issue.

Comment: I am checking will update soon.

Comment: I tried above suggestion, but unluckily it didn't work. Further my concern is in-spite of junk characters in Database table, Content.svc is able to read same content and show properly but OData.svc is not, something need to be configured differently for Odata service. Please let me know.

Comment: Found something, which I am exploring https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/component-presentations-in-sql-2012-db-shows-up-as-a-different-encoding-with-201